# Хранения адресов и телефонов в таблице

Tags: mysql

Возник вопрос при создании таблицы. Делаю таблицу пользователей. Нужно заносить информацию: адрес проживания и адрес регистрационной прописки. Как лучше сделать все это, что пришло сразу в голову, так это сделать поля:

```
*для адрес регистрации:*
-город
-район
-улица и номер дома

*адрес прописки:*
-город2
-район2
-улица и номер дома2
```

Все это в одной таблице, но получается дублирования полей. То же самое и с телефоном, может быть один телефон, а может быть и 2 телефона. Как по мне, дублирования полей - не совсем правильное решения. Видел, делают одно поле для телефона и заносят данные в формате json.

Comment: Телефоны вынести в отдельную таблицу, для адресов одну таблицу и сделать доп. поле, которое будет помечать адрес прописки это или регистрации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что вы хотите реализовать, называется нормализацией таблицы, и это очень правильно, что вы захотели ее осуществить. Обычно сюда приходят те, кто борется с последствиями отказа от нормализации.

Вам нужно сделать отдельные таблицы "телефон" и "адрес":

```
телефон
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT
  phone VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
  owner INTEGER NOT NULL
адрес
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT
  city VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
  district VARCHAR(64) NULL
  street VARCHAR(128) NULL
  building VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
```

И в основной таблице ссылаться на адрес по его id, а в таблице телефонов ссылаться на основную запись через owner.

> Видел делают одно поля для телефона и заносят данные в формате json.

Эт когда человек любит переделывать все по два раза и хочет написать все красиво, но не сейчас, а через полгода.

Comment: а промежуточная таблица users_address тоже нужна же? У одного пользователя обезательно будет же 2 адреса, это телефон необязательный. Получается связь один ко многим. Или я не так понимаю.

Comment: @depredator, если у пользователя всегда два адреса - можно использовать два поля, можно промежуточную таблицу. Если у него их много или просто нефиксированное количестов - тогда только через таблицу.

Comment: @Etki Я надеюсь, Вы не считаете, что предложенная Вами таблица "адрес" находится в 3НФ? В этой таблице улица Джевахрлала Неру повторится столько раз, сколько на ней домов и квартир. Примерно столько же будет и ошибок в названии.

Comment: @BuilderC да вы, батенька, перфекционист. Если мы хотим полностью нормализовать, то, конечно, для городов, улиц и районов нужно заводить отдельные таблицы, а сам проект внеапно превратится в кладр.